# Windows 11 Logon Credentials Failed Check when not on corporate network

Tags: windows-11, login

We have a Windows 11 user who is unable to login to their laptop unless it is connected to the corporate network. The error we get is 'Credentials Failed Check’.

This is the only Windows 11 user so we are trying to understand if this is a Windows 11 issue as none of our Windows 10 users experience any issues.

Comment: Are you able to authenticate on what I presume is an AD domain?

Comment: Try all the remedies that apply from [this page](https://thegeekpage.com/we-cant-sign-you-with-this-credential-because-your-domain-isnt-available/), and please report on what happened for each one. Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1758750/edit) your post rather than answering in comments.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it was ESET Authentication that was causing the issue. Once this was removed, the user was able to login.

We are now investigating why ESET wouldn't let the user login when not on a corporate network.